# KeyChain asks for Touch ID and password multiple times

Tags: macos, password, keychain

Whenever I need to view some WiFi password, KeyChain requests me to enter Touch ID, then it asks to input user login/password, and sometimes (when I don't use it for a long time) it requests for login/password again! It a bit irritates, so how can I make it less aggressive?

MacOS versions: 11.2.3 Big Sur

[image: KeyChain PW messages]